# Render HTML data within the JSON object to UI using Flask

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

I am working on search engine project. In which user will search for query and i'll show the result on the UI. I am using python for computing the best searched result and flask for rendering the result on UI. I am returning JSON object (a dictionary) to the UI, which contains the documentId and its text. Showing text on UI is simple and already done it but now I want to highlight the keywords in the document text. I am putting keyword before sending the dictionary object to the UI.

I have used Markup function before adding text to the JSON object but it didn't work.

```
def getSearchQuery():
    resultSet = callSearch(request.form['query'])
    return render_template('index.html', result=resultSet)
```

```
def callSearch(searchQuery):
    resultData = {'doc1':'Sample <span style="background:yellow;">data</span> from doc1'}
    return resultData
```

index.html

```
{% for docId in result.keys() %}
<p>{{docId}}{{reslut[docId]}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I have tried Markup function:

```
from flask import Markup

def callSearch(searchQuery):
    resultData = {'doc1':Markup('Sample <span style="background:yellow;">data</span> from doc1')}
return resultData
```

It didn't work too.

On UI it must hightlight the keyword instead of plain text.
e.g. In my case, data will be highlighted in the text: Sample data from doc1

Comment: If you already have HTML then send it to template and use `{{ reslut[docId] | safe }}` to inform template to use it as-is.

Comment: I don't have complete html during computation. I am just adding css property to some of the text and then adding this text to the template. Yes, I can create complete html at backend and can send it as plain html too.